# React not displaying data from webapi

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, webapi

I built a webapi using .NET Core, and I can use Postman to get data from the webapi.

I am using React for the front end and I cannot seem to get the data to show.

The webapi is already running in the background.

In React, I created the following .env file to use the webapi:

```
 REACT_APP_API=http:http://localhost:5000/api/
```

My app.js file looks like this:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import {Home} from './Home';
import {Department} from './Department';
import {Employee} from './Employee';
import {Navigation} from './Navigation';

import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
 return (
  <BrowserRouter>
   <div className="container">
     <h3 className="m-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
      React JS
     </h3>

     <Navigation/>

     <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
      <Route path="/department" component={Department} />
      <Route path="/employee" component={Employee}/>
     </Switch>
   </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Since I'm trying to get the department data to show up, I am using the following Department.js file, which reads as follows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Table} from 'react-bootstrap';

export class Department extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={deps:[]}
}

refreshList(){
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'department')
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=>{
        this.setState({deps:data});
    });
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.refreshList();
}

componentDidUpdate(){
    this.refreshList();
}

render(){
    const {deps}=this.state;
    return(
        <div>
            <Table className="mt-4" striped bordered hover size="sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>DepartmentId</th>
                        <th>DepartmentName</th>
                        <th>Options</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {deps.map(dep=>
                        <tr key={dep.DepartmentId}>
                            <td>{dep.DepartmentId}</td>
                            <td>{dep.DepartmentName}</td>
                            <td>Edit / Delete</td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )
 }
}
```

When I start React (using npm start), I should be able to see the departments listed in my database table, as I did when using Postman, but the records are not showing.

I am getting a console error that reads:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

But I'm not sure where exactly that error is pointing to.

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request made to the server?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but how would I know which one is the AJAX request?

Comment: It would be whichever request is invoked at the expected time or event in your application logic (in this case when the component is loaded?) and is directed at the expected URL for the request.  Some browsers include options to filter requests as well.  For example in Chrome you can click on "Fetch/XHR" which should filter the list to only AJAX requests.

Comment: @David  - If I'm looking at this correctly, the file that should be returning the data is Department.  And when I click on Department, in the preview window, it reads, "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app".  Perhaps that may be the issue?

Comment: That sounds like it may indeed be the problem.  If the AJAX request is expecting a JSON response but is receiving an HTML response then that would result in the error described.  You may need to further debug the request being made and how the server is handling that request, as it sounds like it's responding with the page which contains the React app instead of responding with API data.

Comment: My problem turned out to be a typo.  SMH.  Not sure if I can delete this question, but I'll give upvotes to everyone who helped.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem...

In the .env file, it was reading:

```
REACT_APP_API=http:http://localhost:5000/api/
```

But should have been:

```
REACT_APP_API=http://localhost:5000/api/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server probably requires you to specify the content type, if it accepts multiple types

```
fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'department', {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=>{
        this.setState({deps:data});
    });
```

Comment: I added the piece of code you suggested, and in the network tab, department shows the following in the preview window: "Cannot GET /http://localhost:5000/api/department"

Comment: Check your environment variable, and try opening that url on your browser to see if it is responding. Try the URL from console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'department) by calling that somewhere in your code